# Spring boot oauth2 client with Azure AD, but common tenantID

Tags: azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I've set azure parameters with tenantID, everything works well for user from my company in the AD. But i want to authentify external users (Manifest with `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`).

The doc says that i should replace the tenant-id with "common" for the token and authorize urls.

I've configured spring boot oauth2 client with

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
             provider:
                azure:
                    issuer-uri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/v2.0"
                    token-uri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"
                    authorization-uri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
                    user-info-uri: "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo"
                    jwk-set-uri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/discovery/v2.0/keys"
```

I've an exception:

> Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
> The jwt is not validated, nothing match,
> the kid in the jwt header is not in the list `https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX/discovery/v2.0/keys`

In another and, if I set
`jwk-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys`

it contains the right kid, but the token is rejected with this exception:

> [invalid_id_token] The ID Token contains invalid claims:
> {iss=https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX/v2.0}

What is the right way to integrate AzureAD with external users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you put as `issuer-uri` in your conf must be exactly the value of the `iss` claim in your tokens (even the trailing slash, if any, is important).

If you have more than one possible issuers for the tokens you want to accept, then you are in a typical [multi-tenant scenario](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html#oauth2resourceserver-multitenancy). If all this tenants are known at startup (for instance `https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/v2.0` and `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0`), then it is "static" multi-tenancy that you can implement by configuring the authentication manager as stated in the *"Resolving the Tenant By Claim"* section of the doc I linked, or by using [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#oidc-starter) which allows to do that with just application properties.